# Exclamation (!) Removed from CMD %CD% Output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, escaping, delayedvariableexpansion

The Windows CMD shell is stripping the "`!`" character from directory names.

Assume the current working directory is "`C:\\!MyFolder`"

Inside a .CMD file I use this syntax:

```
set _STARTPATH=%CD%
echo %_STARTPATH%
```

`C:\MyFolder` is displayed without the bang (`!`)

This is common from WinXP through Win8.1.

Q: does anybody know a work-around for this?

Comment: You have delayed expansion enabled and the parser consumes the `!`.

Comment: These kinds of parsing quirks should make you want to switch to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

When you enabled delayed expansion you should use it also for the variable expansion

```
set _STARTPATH=!CD!
echo !_STARTPATH!
```

Answer (score 1):

in `delayedexpansion` you can try [variable search/replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) by [escaping](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) `!`:

```
echo %cd:!=^^!%
```

But the solution would be to [disable](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html) [`delayed expansion`](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) momentarily

```
...
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
echo %cd%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
...
```

.

```
@echo off
setlocal
rd !MyFolder
md !MyFolder
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo enabledelayedexpansion is ON
@timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
echo dir /b /ad "^!*"
echo.
dir /b /ad "^!*"

@timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
echo.
echo cd ^^^^^^^^^^^!Myfolder 7 more caret to show double caret ecaping ^^! in echo - 13 carets used in that line.
echo cd ^^!Myfolder double caret to escape ^^!
echo cd "^!Myfolder" single caret inside double quotes to escape ^^!
cd ^^!Myfolder

@timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
echo.
echo ^^^!cd^^^!: !cd!
echo %%cd%%: %cd:!=^^!%

@timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul

endlocal

echo.
echo %%cd%% and  ^!cd^! after endlocal:
@timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
echo %cd%
echo !cd!

exit /b 0
```

Comment: Instead of another `setlocal` command you could state `endlocal & set VAR=%CD%` to restore the previous environment; the value of `VAR` will be transferred to that environment then...

Comment: @aschipfl This works not reliable in any case, as exclamation marks are affected by the expansion mode, and the mode you enter with `endlocal` can also be an `enable delayed` mode

Comment: @paul `echo %cd:!=^^!%` looks nice but `echo !cd!` works also and it is safer, as it works even with carets inside the path

Comment: @jeb, Paul is disabling delayed expansion, so I was talking about using the `endlocal` line instead of his _second_ `setlocal`, so it should work...

Comment: @aschipfl I don't think so, as you are in EDE (Enabled Delayed Expansion) before `setlocal Disable...`, but then the `endlocal & set var=%CD%` would fail, as the `set var=%CD%` will be executed in EDE mode again. But perhaps, I simply missed your point ...

Comment: @jeb, `setlocal disabledelayedexpansion`, then `endlocal & set VAR=%CD%`, so the `set` command and the expansion occur without delayed expansion...

Comment: @aschipfl I just noticed if I do `endlocal` after `cd ^^!Myfolder` I lose the change directory. Probably excepted behaviour.

Comment: @Paul, I don't get what you mean; the current directory won't change after `endlocal`...

Comment: @aschipfl but it change :) I will update my post with example

Comment: An `endlocal` restores also the `CD` variable, so the current directory changes back when it was changed inside the setlocal/endlocal block